# Python tkinter widgets not showing

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

I have created two widgets: a label and a canvas they are inside of a class and in the **init** method of the class. For some reason, none of the widgets show up and it just gives me a blank tkinter window.

```
def __init__ (self, master):
    self.mousepos = 0,0
    self.clickpos = 0,0
    self.poslabel = Label(master, text = "Mouse Click: " \
                          + str(self.clickpos) + "Cursor Point: "\
                          + str(self.mousepos))
    self.poslabel.pack()
    self.fcanvas = Canvas(master,width=800,height=400, bg = 'grey90',\
                          borderwidth = 5, relief = RAISED)
    self.fcanvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.pressButton1)
    self.fcanvas.pack()
```

Comment: What do you pass as master? Please provide full code

Comment: I think that might be the problem. This is what I started with (excluding initialise tkinter)

Answer (score 2):

If that is all of your code, you're forgetting to run the `mainloop` method of your root window. Window drawing happens via events that are processed by the event loop; if it doesn't run, the windows don't get the opportunity to draw themselves on the screen.

Comment: No i have initialized the tkinter. I found the problem was somewhere else the app window was directing to another class.

Answer (score 2):

For reference here is a working version of your code. Notice how I passed **root** for the master argument. Also, take note of how I used the **.mainloop()** method on root.

Tkinter runs in a loop, if you don't call the **.mainloop()** method your program won't run properly.

This should work:

```
from Tkinter import *

class MyWidgets :
    def __init__ (self, master) :
        self.mousepos = 0,0
        self.clickpos = 0,0
        self.poslabel = Label(master, text = "Mouse Click: " \
                              + str(self.clickpos) + "Cursor Point: "\
                              + str(self.mousepos))
        self.poslabel.pack()

        self.fcanvas = Canvas(master, width=800,height=400, bg = 'grey90',\
                              borderwidth = 5, relief = RAISED)
        self.fcanvas.bind("<Button-1>", self.pressButton1)
        self.fcanvas.pack()

    def pressButton1 (self, event) :
        print 'You pressed button 1!'

if __name__ == '__main__' :

    root = Tk()
    MyWidgets(root)
    root.mainloop()
```