# Python 3, tkinter, widgets not showing up

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, notepad++

I'm using Python 3, `tkinter` module in Windows 10. I know the question has been asked frequently, but none of the questions on this forum (or any other result from google) seems to have the answer. I tried to get started with tkinter (which I have never used before), but each really basic working example only returns the main tkinter GUI window and no widgets. I've tried to run most of the solutions to questions asked on this forum as well (like [Python tkinter widgets not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933993/python-tkinter-widgets-not-showing), [Tkinter widgets not appearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062978/tkinter-widgets-not-appearing) or [Tkinter widgets not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779875/tkinter-widgets-not-showing)), but the same result (just the main window, no adjustments to the main window or any widgets are showing).

My current MWE is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

top = Tk()
top.geometry("100x100")

def helloCallBack():
   msg = messagebox.showinfo( "Hello Python", "Hello World")

B = Button(top, text = "Hello", command = helloCallBack)
B.place(x = 50,y = 50)

top.mainloop()
```

[I am following this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_gui_programming.htm). No errors show up.
The result is shown in the attached picture:

[image: Return of running the MWE]

I run the code in cmd via `Notepad++`, which works fine for all normal python code not involving tkinter.

Comment: I ran your code in ipython it worked

Comment: And it also worked in python IDLE.

Comment: Code works from the console on linux as well.

Comment: Thank you all for checking, do you have any idea on how to make it work for Notepad++? Do you require more information?

Comment: I noticed that the button seemed to be off on the edge of the window... so I commented out the window geometry line, have you tried to resize your window or just skip the geometry line? just a second thought.

Comment: Thanks, I just commented out the geometry line and resized the GUI window to fullscreen, but no improvement.
I think it might have something to do with calling the modules, but I have little experience with this and don't really know how to change any of it

Comment: Your code would not work for us if it was an issue with your imports. do you have another means of running your code?

Comment: I can try installing IDLE. But it should be able to work on Notepad++ as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: if you use `B.place(relx=0.5,rely = 0.5)`, does the button show up?

Comment: And also try with `B.place(x = 0,y = 0)`

Comment: No it doesn't, but thank you. The code works when running in Python IDLE

Comment: See if you replace the place with pack, then the code runs or not i.e. do B.pack()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
B = Button(top, text = "Hello", command = helloCallBack).pack(top)
```

instead of:

```
B = Button(top, text = "Hello", command = helloCallBack)
B.place(x = 50,y = 50)
```

Place can be used to set where you want stuff to appear in a window.